# Is there a way to connect Youtrack to Hipchat?

Tags: youtrack, hipchat

I searched a lot on Google and Stackoverflow but I didn't find anything explaining how to connect Youtrack to Hipchat.

Is it possible ? 
And if it is, any help or link would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I've not tried it myself, but I guess connecting YouTrack as a Hipchat Jabber client should do the trick. To set this up on YouTrack side go to /settings.

Comment: I had already seen the "Jabber Notifications" part on the YouTrack settings, but I have absolutely no idea of which Jabber server and Jabber username I should use, where can I find these informations on HipChat ?

Comment: This page, for instance, provides the instructions on how to connect to Hipchat using Miranda IM, but it also gives you an idea which url and username to use: https://help.hipchat.com/knowledgebase/articles/64438-how-to-connect-using-miranda

Comment: @Simon Were you able to integrate Youtrack with Hipchat? I'm looking to find out if there is proper integration similar to how hipchat integrates with Jira.